# парсер изображений на php

Tags: php

В php вообще ноль, но по работе потребовалось, так как на js данная задача невыполнима, прошу помощи. Есть кусочек парсера, принимает на вход ссылку, парсит и получает url изображений, пишет в массив. Но нужно еще получить разрешение изображение и его размер в килобайтах. Нагуглил функции getimagesize() и filesize(), осталось придумать куда их впихнуть, и как это подобающе вывести. Предполагаю что в цикле нужно эти функции с массивом использовать, но не работает.

```php
        $data  = file_get_contents('https://habr.com/ru/company/lsfusion/blog/458376/');
        $images = array();
        preg_match_all('/(img|src)=("|\')[^"\'>]+/i', $data, $media);
        unset($data);
        $data = preg_replace('/(img|src)("|\'|="|=\')(.*)/i', "$3", $media[0]);

        foreach ($data as $url) {
            $info = pathinfo($url);
            if (isset($info['extension'])) {
                if (($info['extension'] == 'jpg') ||
                        ($info['extension'] == 'jpeg') ||
                        ($info['extension'] == 'png'))
                    array_push($images, $url);
            }
        }
        print_r($images);
```

Comment: Советую заглянуть https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Благодарю, был на этом ресурсе, и с радостью бы получше в php разобрался, если бы сроки не горели.

Comment: Очень странно что вы там были и это не помогло =) `$im = new Imagick();$im->readimage($uploadfile."[0]");$imageprops = $im->getImageGeometry();if ($imageprops['width'] <= 175 && $imageprops['height'] <= 300);` Это прям с того сайта =) думаю этого куска кода достаточно для задачи "определить" разрешение изображения =)

Comment: @Reep "так как на js данная задача невыполнима" - а вы вообще решение искали? простой поиск в гугле +100500 разных решений выдает

Comment: @Ghost а каким образом вы сможете обратиться на чужой сервер с помощью js, и обойти при этом защиту?

Comment: @Reep о какой защите идет речь? axios.get('www.google.com')